# Java Random Walk Program?

Tags: java, random

I am trying to write a program that takes a random walk from a center point (0,0) 100 times and calculates the average number of steps taken. I have the following code:

```
package randomwalk;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomWalk {
   int x = 0; 
   int y = 0;
   int steps = 0;
   Random r = new Random();  
   public RandomWalk(){


   do {
       int num = randInt(1,4);
       if(num == 1){
           this.x+=1;

       }
       else if(num == 2){
           this.x-=1;
       }

       else if(num == 3){
           this.y+=1;
       }
       else if(num == 4){
           this.y-=1;
       }

       this.steps++;


   } while(this.x != 0 || this.y != 0);

   }

   public int getSteps(){
   return this.steps;
   }


   public static int randInt(int min, int max){
   Random r = new Random(); 
   int num  = r.nextInt((max-min) + 1) + min;
   return num;
   }
}
```

I also have the test function:

```
package randomwalk;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int total = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        RandomWalk rand  = new RandomWalk();
        int steps = rand.getSteps();
        total+=steps;
    }
    System.out.println("The average is: " + ((total/2) / 100));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? My program seems to always run infinitely and I never get a return value. It just keeps running. Help is appreciated!

Comment: From **center point (0,0)** to where? Or just back to **center point (0,0)**?

Comment: @Reno back to center point

Comment: Now we're clear, Actually it always runs infinitely, this loop, you want when `this.x==0` and `this.y==0`, loop breaks, but this condition is quite critical and this loop will even do 100 times. We cant predicate what `Random` return to us. So you should give additional condition to this loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop while x is not 0 or y is not 0. Since by random generation you are not guaranteed to ever get back to 0, the program can run forever. You might want to try limiting your loop by the number of steps a walker takes.

```
while (steps < 100)
```

instead of

```
while (this.x != 0 || this.y != 0)
```

Comment: You want to check both conditions: `(this.x != 0 || this.y != 0) && steps < 100` since the whole point is to find out how many steps it takes to get back to the center. And then you need to do something special in your main method if the number of steps equals the maximum. But of course this is going to skew the average.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to print out the x,y position every thousand steps or so.  That way if there's a bug (x always increases, for example) it will become obvious.  But I think the real issue is that statistically speaking your walk never returns to 0,0.

Comment: I just wrote my own random walk.  Most runs finished after less than 100 steps.  A few took > 10,000 steps.  One I killed manually after 1,000,000 steps.  If the initial x or y gets very large, then it appears unlikely both x and y will ever be able to return to 0 at the same time.